# Why does thunkify / yield always return an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yield, thunk, co

I have a `thunk` called **logInline** (adapted from the [Co documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/co)).

I notice the thunkified `get` always seems to `yield` an array. Is this by design? Is it `thunkify` doing this, or is it a standard part of `yield`?

```
var co = require('co'),
  get = thunkify(request.get);

var logInline = co(function *(){
  var google = yield get('http://google.com'); 
  console.log(google[0].statusCode);
})

logInline()
```

Note the variable 'google' here is always an array. Why? Note that `request.get` normally returns `err, response` (ie, there are no arrays).

The script, BTW, returns `200` or whatever other response code google.com returns.

Alas [the yield documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) is pretty sparse ATM.

**Edit:** Thunks don't always return arrays. Eg if `var readFile = thunkify(fs.readFile);`:

```
var fileContents = yield readFile('myfile', 'utf8');
log(fileContents);
```

In this case, fileContents is not returned inside an array. So why was google inside an array?
**There seems to be something in thunkify controlling what the thunks return**

Comment: It is just a guess as I didn't have time to look at `yield` and `thunkify`, but there is a similar behavior with `when` and `node.lift`. As the callback method that is _wrapped_ by it could have (beside the `err`) more then one argument, the result is always an array where `a[0]` is the first argument, `a[1]` the second, ...

Answer (score 5):

> I notice the thunkified get always seems to yield an array. Is this by design?

I don't know and cannot confirm, as you say the docs (of co, `yield` is not of interest here) are quite sparse.

I could however image that the `yield` does result in the arguments-array of the callback, to easily support multiple return values. You might use a destructuring assignment to get the single results back:

```
co(function *(){
  var [google] = yield get('http://google.com'); 
  console.log(google.statusCode);
})
```

---

Edit:

> There seems to be something in thunkify controlling what the thunks return

Indeed, this happens only sometimes. I now checked [the code](https://github.com/visionmedia/co/blob/8446e81ef29e72561e73073394cef9e93ae8dcc9/index.js#l59), which reads

```
if (arguments.length > 2) res = slice.call(arguments, 1);
```

so if the callback function (of the thunkified call, but imagine it to be the one that is passed to `fs.readFile` or `request.get` directly) is called with more than one result argument (the error parameter is ignored), then an array will be `yield`ed to your generator code.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like destructuring assignment is still on the way in Node ATM (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379277/destructuring-in-node-js) so I currently do `var google = (yield get('http://google.com'))[0];`

Comment: Aww, I had expected them to work… FF does support them for so long :-/