# Destructuring syntax error in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

can someone help me to understand what is wrong on this:

```js
var foo = {
  bar: 1,
  baz: 2
};

var { bar, baz } = foo;
```

I got error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. I'm using node v5.4.1 So I'm not sure if problem is in node or in syntax. For example `let` works well. Many thanks

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17379714/419956) help?

Answer (score 0):

Node does not yet support all ES6 specifications. Destructuring is not supported as mentioned here https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

You need to pass by a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm using babel, but nothing changed:    
`require("babel-core").transform("code", {"presets": ["es2015"]});`