# Array destructuring assignment not working in v8 with harmony option in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8, destructuring

I want to learn how to enable harmony v8 options in Node, and my node version is:

```
$ node -v                                                                      
v5.5.0
```

Use ES6 destructuring as an example for testing

```
$ cat destructure.js
'use strict'
var a, b
[a, b]  = [1, 2] 
console.log(a, b)
```

Run it straight gets error as expected.

```
$ node destructure.js 
/usr/home/mko_io/pure-js-files/destructure.js:3
[a, b]  = [1, 2]
^^^^^^
```

But get the same error, after the flag has been set:

```
$ node --harmony_destructuring destructure.js 
/usr/home/mko_io/pure-js-files/destructure.js:3
[a, b]  = [1, 2]
^^^^^^

ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Where did I do it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is/was a bug in the V8 JavaScript engine.

```
'use strict'
var a, b
[a, b]  = [1, 2] 
console.log(a, b)
```

Does not work but...

```
'use strict'
var [a, b]  = [1, 2] 
console.log(a, b)
```

does work, when using the `--harmony_destructuring`.

Looks like the experimental feature is not yet fully spec-compliant.

The [relevant bug report for V8](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4636) marked this issue as fixed in December 2015, so now we just need to wait for the updated V8 to make it into Node. [@mscdex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050455/mscdex) has informed me this fix will be available in Node v6.0.0.

Comment: It already works in node master and thus will be in the upcoming node v6.0.0.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I thought enabling the v8 flag could enable me to learn the new feature easy comparing to testing in browser.

Comment: Nit: it wasn't a bug, it's just that despite looks, destructuring (binding) and destructuring _assignment_ are entirely separate features (in terms of both language spec and implementation), and V8 shipped the former first. The latter followed behind the `--harmony-destructuring-assignment` flag.

Comment: Or you can upgrade to Node 6.5v

Answer (score 1):

Destructure is broken.

> In progress features can be activated individually by their respective harmony flag (e.g. --harmony_destructuring), although this is highly discouraged unless for testing purposes.

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/ and this answer [Destructuring in Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379277/destructuring-in-node-js)