# using parallel array assignment with therubyracer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, v8, therubyracer

while calling V8::Context#load, therubyracer complains

```
Unexpected token [ at /home/dm/contra/app/assets/javascripts/libfigure/figure.js:120:10
```

That ends up being `var [ who` in the middle of this function:

```
function allemande_orbit_view(move,pvs) {
    var who = pvs[0]
    var [ who, dir, inner_angle, outer_angle, beats] = pvs
    var [swho,sdir,sinner_angle,souter_angle,sbeats] = parameter_strings(move, pvs)
...
```

It's complaing about using a destructuring array assignment, like this:

```
var [a,b] = [5,6]
```

I see that later versions of V8 support this ( [Array destructuring assignment not working in v8 with harmony option in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076782/array-destructuring-assignment-not-working-in-v8-with-harmony-option-in-node-js) ), but if I put `gem 'libv8', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.281.59.1'` in my `Gemfile`, then bundler tells me to buss off:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "libv8":
  In Gemfile:
    libv8 (>= 5.1.281.59.1, ~> 5.1)

    therubyracer was resolved to 0.12.2, which depends on
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
```

I look at therubyracer github page, and see the last update a year ago, and only then for v8 4.5, and it looks like it was not going well.

Sooo.... I think I'm hosed on upgrading V8, right?

Anyone know how to pass the `--harmony_restructuring` flag to the existing V8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libv8` maintainer here.

Unfortunately `therubyracer` is incompatible with versions of V8 greater than 3.16 at this point.

If you are using it just as a JS runtime for asset compilation you should consider switching to the brand new [`mini_racer`](https://github.com/discourse/mini_racer) instead.

As a side note, you should consider asking the maintainers of a project directly first, through their issue tracker for example, before shooting a question in SO. Your question probably would have remained unanswered had I not been by chance looking for recent questions about libv8 here.