# destructuring assignment on array `process.argv` return Cannot read property 'next on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using nodejs when using destructuring assignment on array `process.argv` I get error `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined`.

How to fix this issue? Why is that?
Notes: I am using node v6.9.1

```
let fileIn, fileOut;
let getNodeArguments = () => {
    // this is ok
    process.argv.forEach((val, index) => {
         console.log(`${index}: ${val}`);
    });
    // this is ok
    var hasFileInOutArgs = process.argv.length === 4;
    if (!hasFileInOutArgs) {
        throw ('arguments for file-in and file-out must be provided');
    }
    // issue
    var [, , argUrlIn, argUrlOut] = process.argv;  // error exception here <<<
    fileIn = argUrlIn;
    fileOut = argUrlOut;
};
getNodeArguments();
```

More infos:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring

Comment: I would like to create two variable argUrlIn and argUrlIn which are populate with value from process.argv process[2] and process[3]

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: I am using v6.9.1

Comment: could be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379277/destructuring-in-node-js

Comment: Your code works fine in Node 6.2.2.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that in Node v6.9.1.

Comment: how do you know it breaks there? the problem is in next() which is nowhere in the code you shown?

Comment: Thanks guys for your hint, I have notice that code run fine when I run in node directly, but I get an error when debugging it using latest version of visual studio code. Do you know how could fix this issue on VSCODE?

Comment: It is always as simple as `var [, , argUrlIn, argUrlOut] = process.argv || [];`, Don't forget to assign default values if they aren't supposed to be undefined.