# failing a build in jenkins

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

What could be the issue of this build ? Im not sure what exactly causing it? Is it nodejs?

```
/home/deploy/swarm/workspace/Project/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js:331
    .then(([size, source]) => {
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/deploy/swarm/workspace/Project/webpack.config.prod.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! Project build: `webpack -p --config webpack.config.prod.js`
```

Comment: node `v4.x.x` does not support array destructuring like so `[size, source]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/17379714/2880747

Comment: Addendum: https://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--declarations